# Change file name [Ionic 4]

Tags: file, ionic4, crud, ionic-native

I´m currently working on an Ionic 4 mobile app (Android and iOS) where I should let the user do https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file but I don´t seem to find a way to change the file name, I can create new files, delete them or modify the content, but I´m not able to change the file name. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

PS. I can´t delete the old file and create a new one with the same content and differente name since I´m working with blockchain and by doing that I would lose all the file history.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
renameFile(currentName, currentDir, newName, onSuccess, onFail) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, (fileSystem) => {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(currentDir + currentName, null, (fileEntry) => {
            fileSystem.root.getDirectory(currentDir, {create: true, exclusive: false}, (dirEntry) => {
                parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry(currentName, currentDir + currentName);

                fileEntry.moveTo(dirEntry, newName, () => {
                    onSuccess();
                }, onFail);
            }, onFail);
        }, onFail);
    }, onFail);
}
```